# How to disable user interaction of NSTextView?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

In Cocoa Touch, you can disable user interaction of a text view like this:

```
let textView = UITextView()
textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

But in Cocoa, NSTextView has no such easy API to use.
So what's the proper way to disable NSTextView user interaction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable its' `editable`  by:

```
textView.isEditable = false
```

And its' `selectable` by:

```
textView.isSelectable = false
```

However, when you disable both of them. This textView still will intercept Mouse-down event, which is different from `isUserInteractionEnabled` .

So, for now, to enable click-through, my solution is subclassing a `NSTextView` and override its' hitTest:

```
class TextView: NSTextView {
  override func hitTest(_ point: NSPoint) -> NSView? {
    return nil
  }
}
```

**An encapsulated way is here**

```
class StaticTextView: NSTextView {
  override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
    super.init(frame: frameRect)
  }

  override init(frame frameRect: NSRect, textContainer container: NSTextContainer?) {
    super.init(frame: frameRect, textContainer: container)
  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
  }

  override func hitTest(_ point: NSPoint) -> NSView? {
    return nil
  }
}
```